# Android AVD Manager Linux, Error: No space left on device Error: AVD not created

Tags: android, linux, android-virtual-device

I am running android-sdk-linux on my kali linux KDE Laptop which is having a problem when trying to create an avd when I use the GUI or the AVD Manager it says no space left on device and when trying to use command line it says Error: No space left on device
Error: AVD not created. I am clueless as what the problem could be, because I don't see many reports on this... I am trying to make an android 5.01 Virtual Device with armeabi-v7a

Also when I am done the AVD appears in /root/.android/avd
But when I run it using ./emulator @AVD1 I get:
PANIC: Could not open AVD config file: /root/.android/avd/AVD1.avd/config.ini

And I checked and that file doesnt even exist!

Comment: "Device" means the computer where you're running the AVD, not the AVD itself. How much free space do you have on that hard drive?

Comment: @MikeLaren Weird when I type df -k it isnt shwoing my current partition but my other linux partition...

Comment: Do you have a `/` partition or a `/home`? Which OS are you using?